# GTK3 Statusbar Height

Tags: gtk3, gtk2, pcmanfm

I've recently updated a few programs to gtk3 (deadbeef gtk3 plugin, pcmanfm-gtk3, l3afpad) and there's one thing that's really been bugging me:

Why is the Statusbar thrice the height of the gtk2 version?

It's clearly not because there's more information or a bigger font - the text is the same for both versions, it's just a 10 px margin for the statusbar in gtk3.
So I thought "hey, gtk3 has some nice CSS, maybe I can tweak that with gtk.css oder settings.ini" - turns out that nah, not really.
Any stuff in gtk.css like

```
    GtkStatusbar { margin:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; }
```

doesn't do anything, sadly.

So I tried playing around with GtkInspector in pcmanfm.
When I select the whole Statusbar element (you have to select the whitespace between the left and the right labels, only 10 px wide) and I check the properties, I see theres a 10 px value for all margins defined for GtkWidget (except for bottom and top, those are 6).
Now if I doubleclick that value and set "all margins" to 0 it immediately gives me a gtk2 statusbar - rejoice!

So I know it is possible, but I just haven't found a way to get that into gtk.css. I got desperate enough to try:

```
GtkWidget { margin:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; }
```

but I didn't really expect it to work - so of course it didn't.

I've also tried searching for solutions online, but I've only ended up with a few very specific tips to downgrade eclipse from gtk3 to gtk2 in order to save screen space or [this](http://git.mate-desktop.org/engrampa/commit) patch to engrampa that removes those margins.

Hell, it could be there's some GUI-Tool for GNOME that does this in like 5 seconds, and I've been searching for the wrong stuff all along.

Comment: You should mention your version of GTK3: `dpkg -l libgtk-3-0`

Comment: gtk3 version is 3.18.9-1 - I'm on archlinux

Comment: Sorry to bug you without providing an answer, but which theme are you using? Some themes are difficult to tweak. These themes have gtk3 files like `*.scss` (Arc or Numix) or have binary "blobs" (Adwaita).

Comment: I'm using Numix (with gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=1, so its the dark one) - but in /usr/share/themes/Numix/gtk-3.0/ I couldnt find any *.scss-files, just the normal *.css ones

Comment: after updating gtk to 3.20 and numix to 2.5.1 - now everthing is huge. this would look really lovely with 2x the font size on 4k, but on 1080p it just redefined waste of space for me...

Answer (score 0):

This helps somewhat:

```
gtk_widget_set_margin_top(GTK_WIDGET(statusbar), 0);
gtk_widget_set_margin_bottom(GTK_WIDGET(statusbar), 0);
```

Comment: uhm, that doesnt look like css or ini-code or anything I can change as a user. is this code that the maintainer could use to reduce the margin?

Comment: No, it has to be set in the program code. This is not configureable through CSS.